# Is selecting across pages(grid pagination) supported in Clarity grid batch action?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity, clarity

https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/batch-action
On the clarity grid, can we keep selecting rows/items across the grid pages and perform a batch/bulk action?

Like select some rows on Page 1 and select some more rows on Page 2 and not losing on the selections of Page 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, selection remains active unless you filter the list of items. When you bind to the list of selectable items you'll get all items not just the ones on the current page. You can try this out at https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/full

Comment: Can we have an option to select everything at once. Like lets say the grid has 10000 rows(paginated across 100 pages), and I want to select all of them at once. Is that supported?

Comment: You could do this manually by passing in the full set of items to `[(clrDgSelected)]="selected"`, but the select all button is for the currently visible page only. This was intentional based on UX research.